# Centrar verticalmente dos tamaños de letras

Tags: css, text

Quiero poner un texto entre paréntesis, pero los paréntesis son el doble de tamaño que el texto y al hacerlo todo el teto queda alineado hacia abajo.

He intentado hacer:

```css
.texto {
 color: #FFE5CC;
 font-size: 1rem; 
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.parentesis {
 font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="texto"><span class="parentesis">(</span>  texto  <span class="parentesis">)</span></h3>
```

Pero no centra el texto verticalmente respecto a los paréntesis. 
¿Como lo puedo hacer? Gracias

Comment: puedes poner una imagen de como quieres que quede, porfavor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ello deberías jugar con la propiedad `vertical-align` de css, en tu caso el valor `sub` es el que se amolda.

```css
.texto {
 color: #FFE5CC;
 font-size: 1rem; 
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.parentesis {
 font-size: 2rem;
  vertical-align:sub;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="texto"><span class="parentesis">(</span>  texto  <span class="parentesis">)</span></h3>
```

Comment: Gracias, desconocía la esa propiedad.

Comment: No hay de que, para eso estamos ;)